# attaching a file path in a html form

Tags: html

```
<form>
     <label for="attachment">Attachment:</label> 
     <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to attach the file path to a form. I am doing it using the following code, but I want that the pop up window should open to a specified path, say `D:\newfolder`, so the user doesn't need to go to `D:` and then `newfolder` to attach the file.

Is there any way I can set this predefined path?

Comment: During posting/editing a question/answer you can see the formatting rules at the right column. Read it. Click the provided reference link.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done in any browser for security reasons.

As far as I know, It's also not possible using a Flash-based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org).

You may be able to pre-set the path using an alternative Java-based uploader that has more liberal access to the client's computer, but this feature is hardly worth making the switch to that technology and the additional requirements and hassles it brings along.

Comment: I was about to post the same link , but hit refresh first.

Comment: but i am not attaching any file to server. i just need the file path that too on my local server, still not possible?

Comment: If you just need the file path, and you know what it is … use a text or hidden input.

Comment: i dont know the path. it depends on the file the user chooses

Comment: @sushant ahh I see, you need only the file path and not the file itself. I'm afraid that is not possible reliably either, the user will have to copy+paste the path into a text field.